# how to map a file in RAM by offset and size in windows

Tags: c++, windows, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping, virtualfilesystem

I have a C++ programfind to delete files on hard drive. So the program starts reading from beginning of a partition and whenever it sees a valid signature it'll read that and find the file size according to the what kind of file is.

Then it saves the beginning size and offset of the file into the database. 
Now what I want is giving the files to the some analyzers when this process has done!

What I am doing now is recovering the files into the hard then giving their addresses to the analyzer. But it's too long.

I want to load these files into RAM by a virtual file system that it gets file address offset and file size, then give an virtual address that the analyzers could read that files by `fopen()` and it's get faster but I don't want to write files on partition.

In fact the files has existed into the partition but not in the file system table.

Is there any solution for this way?

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple trick which you have to know. Call `CreateFile` as you do know, but pass `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY`. This is a strong hint to Windows to keep the file in RAM, as you intend to delete it right after use.

You can also pass `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` to make things easier for yourself.

Comment: i dont want to save file on disk at all.I have file offset and size and i want to bring it on ram as a file without writting on hard.In other word i have a stream on ram that i want to map it on a partition whitout make anything on hard

Comment: Well, you don't know whether it's in RAM, do you? Not on any modern OS which has virtual address spaces. You may think it's in RAM and it's really swapped out to disk. Or conversely, you may think it's on disk, but in reality it's in the file cache. I know what you're saying, but I also know how little Windows resembles your mental model.